# People remain in User Information List even after successful AD synch

Tags: user-profile-service

I have a User Profile synchronization service that seems to be working well. The User Profile pages of new staff members are populating correctly, including changed data from AD and our BDC. Users who have left the organization and no longer have active AD accounts no longer have User Profile pages with "User not found". Great. I assume my synchronization is working.

However, when I look at my hidden User Information List I still see users who have left. The UIL is updating correctly for active and new users. It seems just removes aren't working. Any idea what is going on here?

Maureen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal behavior. UPSA does not remove accounts from the UIL during a UPSA -> UIL synchronization.

You can manually 'delete' accounts from the UIL, although in the Content Database they're just marked as deleted (`tp_Deleted = 1`) and not removed. This is to retain referential integrity.

There are automated tools out there as well. The big one I'm familiar with and have used extensively is Metalogix ControlPoint.

Comment: How would you go about manually deleting accounts from the UIL?

Comment: Click on the users name, should take you to a screen showing their details and a link to "Delete user from site collection". They aren't hurting anyone being there, as Trevor mentions it's for integrity purposes. By deleting a user, when clicking on their name in an Assigned To, Created By, or Modified By field, you'll get dumped to an error screen because the user no longer exists.